# Override type name in the drf-spectacular - generated OpenAPI schema

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I'm stuck with what seems like it should be a reasonably simple problem.

I have DRF application, and I use drf-spectacular to generate OpenAPI schema.
In my app, I have a class, let's call it `Foo`, which is fairly deep in the hierarchy of a serialized response. The problem is that for historical reasons I need to keep calling it `Foo` in the code but in the schema I need to refer to it as `Bar`.

There don't appear to be any explicit ways (e.g. decorators) for that, and I haven't figured out how do "override the name" with the general-purpose pre- or post-process hooks. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to include an example of your code, from what I understand you're trying to override a serialiser's name that is used in a hierarchy of a serialized response, to do that you can decorate your `Foo` serializer with [`@extend_schema_serializer`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-4-extend-schema-serializer). Your code will look like this:

```py
    @extend_schema_serializer(component_name="Bar")
    class Foo(serialisers.Serializer): 
        field = .. 
        
    class Foo1(serializers.Serializer):
        foos = Foo(many=True)
```